# Typescript: Create recursive mapped type that maps from existing type to string

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Given a type  how can I write a recursive mapped type that yields a type  that is  with all the same keys but with their types being strings instead of whatever their incoming type is? Specifically, I want to handle nested objects & arrays.

```
type MySourceType = {
  field1 :string,
  field2: number,
  field3: number[],
  field4: Date, 
  field5: {
    nestedField1: number,
    nestedField2: number[]
    nestedField3: Date,
  }
}
```

```
type MyDestinationType = MakeAllFieldsString<MySourceType>;
```

should yield:

```
type MyDestinationType = {
    field1 :string,
    field2: string,
    field3: string[],
    field4: string, 
    field5: {
      nestedField1: string,
      nestedField2: string[]
      nestedField3: string,
    }
  }
```

this works for a regular "flat" object but fails to handle the nested objects and arrays

```
type JsonObject<T> = {[Key in keyof T]: string; }
```

I also tried this but it didn't seem work do what I expected either.

```
type NestedJsonObject<T> = {
[Key in keyof T]: typeof T[Key] extends object ? JsonObject<T[Key]> : string;
}
```

Comment: What is that “`typeof`” doing in your second try? Isn’t there an error there? Does it start working if you just remove `typeof`?

Comment: good catch; I was trying different variations and that is indeed an error. It doesn't work as expected without the typeof though...or at least doesn't do what I hoped it would

Comment: Can you [edit] your question not to include syntax errors so that your example becomes a [mre]?  Also, since `Date` is an object type that you want to become `string` but `{a: number}` is an object type that you *don't* want to become `string`, could you explain how you want the mapping to tell the difference between object types that you *want* to recurse into versus ones that you don't?  Like, we could special-case `Date`, but is that the only one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
type MySourceType = {
  field1: string;
  field2: number;
  field3: number[];
  field4: Date;
  field5: {
    nestedField1: number;
    nestedField2: number[];
    nestedField3: Date;
  };
};

type Literal = { [k: string]: {} };

type JsonObject<T> = T extends Array<infer U>
  ? U extends Literal
  ? Array<JsonObject<U>>
  : Array<string>
  : T extends Literal
  ? { [Key in keyof T]: JsonObject<T[Key]> }
  : string;

type MyDestinationType = JsonObject<MySourceType>;
```

TypeScript playground: https://tsplay.dev/WYBlgw

Comment: Thanks! Two questions - what does the type Literal there do? and second question - array of objects turn into arrays of strings; is there a fix for that?

Comment: Your `Literal` check is a bit strange, since this only happens to work because `MySourceType` is a type alias of an anonymous object type and not an interface.  Do you think OP wants [this](https://tsplay.dev/NaYR6N) to happen if an interface is passed in?  And also, `Literal` won't match anything with values that are nullable, so [this](https://tsplay.dev/WzL7EN) happens.  Not sure if this is the desired behavior here.

Comment: I've provided a fix for the arrays @jcalz what do you suggest as a better solution?

Comment: @James please [edit] the question to demonstrate use cases you care about so that the code there is a [mre].  If "array of objects" is something you have a requirement for, you should show what it is so that people answering don't make assumptions that turn out to be incorrect.

Comment: @GuerricP without details from OP about what they expect to happen in different edge cases I'm not sure.  Apparently the version you posted is what they want because it's been accepted, but I do wonder what they want to see in the cases I highlighted above.

Comment: Yes I'm wondering too. I found this solution to match object literal type and not `Date`. The problem with the `Date`type is that it extends `object`, `{}`, `Object` so none of these types can be used

Comment: Maybe they will provide a list of object types to turn to `string`?  Like, just `Date` and that's it?  ‍♂️

Comment: My thought with this is that I'd like to create ApiResponseType with dates/numbers/nested objects and an ApiResponseTypeJson which is the same thing except is all strings since that's what actually gets recieved. I would then create a function that accepts ApiResponseTypeJson and returns ApiResponseType.

Comment: I accepted the answer since it *does* do exactly as requested. If I add additional criteria then that's moving the goalposts; ideally, it would handle arrays of nested objects though. Is it accepted to add additional requirements to a question?

Comment: The usual practice is to post another question. This one is answered, changing an answered question makes it hard to follow.